# Generate .po file from strings in code (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, localization, translation, poedit

Can someone tell me how to generate .po file for tranlation from my strings in Python3 code? I have a separate file in which I store all my strings, the only texts in my application other then that is documentation for methods and functons (which I do not care to translate). In this file there are only variables with text. I want to generate .po or .pot file with them so I can translate them and then based on user language selection choose which .po file should be read. How can I achieve that? I already tried with some gettext but all information I found wasn't understandable for me. I also tried with Poedit and generate from source, but also without success. Can anyone help me with simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind I found solution.

For those who doesn't know:
You need to import gttext and add gttext(string) with every translation you want to make e.g.

```
from gettext import gettext

menu_options = gettext('''
What do you want to do?
1. Create new object.
2. Read instructions.
3. Exit application.
''')
```

Then open Poedit, create new .pot file and when you will generate from source then you will have these strings. What I do not know et is how to select language from application :)

Comment: `_()` function is often better (it is an alias). You may want to check `babel`, which automate some parts.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I'm doing this in this way: https://pastebin.com/Me1LV8h7

strs. is import from file with strings. if lang == 1 then use English, if lang == 2 use Polish.